# Inexpensive Electronic Task Board

Tags: android, tablet, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for something inexpensive to use as an electronic task board mounted on the wall in a house spending under or close to $50 if possible.

Preferably a 7" screen minimum. 3" seems to small.

Screensaver or screen dimming isn't in the foreground yet but I will want to consider the energy drain and the ambient light late at night with all lights off. If it turns the display off automatically then that would be a plus.

I would also like this to be not too difficult to set up. I'm fine drilling a couple nails in the wall but I'm not interested in attaching a laptop LCD screen to a Raspberry Pi or using a soldering iron.

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B already.

I have a couple tablets already but they're always being used, so I can't put any existing tablet on the wall full-time.

I also don't want to tie up the family room TV with this.

I did see an RCA tablet for around $35 running Android. This might work if the quality of the tablet is good. I've seen tablet picture ledges that could probably be put on the wall, but the charging cord for the tablet won't look appealing.

Once I have this, I'm planning on running one application on it full time that displays a web page. The web page is a custom Node.js application that fetches task list items from my Wunderlist account and renders them the way I want in a browser window, or if necessary an Android app showing a web view.

**EDIT:** A digital picture frame would suffice if I could script periodically regenerating an image of the web page e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image. If the frame supports Wi-Fi, it can display photos stored on my LAN, one or more of which could be a generated image of the current page.